# SQL not return data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want return data that are between @from and @to. Date in DB is nvarchar(max) type. Sql is fine, because when i set @from and @to and run sql code in sql server, return correct result. XML not empty, there are columns name, but not columns data.

```
public static DataSet Report(string from, string to)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Rez");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conf.ConnStrVienaSas))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(FileReaderHelper.ReadSQLText("ExternalReports.sql"), conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@from", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = from;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@to", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = to; 
            using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            try
            {
                adap.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ds = WSErrorExtenderHelper.CreateErrorDS(ex.ToString() /*"Error reading data from DB."*/);
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

SQL fragment:

```
SELECT [A].[FieldValue] AS Created_at, [B].[Created_by], [C].[Code1], 
[D].[Code2], [E].[Code3], [F].[Code4]
FROM [dbo].[TEMP] A with (nolock)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEMP2] B with (nolock)
ON [A].[UserDefinedRowId] = [B].[UserDefinedRowId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEMP3] C with (nolock)
ON [A].[UserDefinedRowId] = [C].[UserDefinedRowId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEMP4] D with (nolock)
ON [A].[UserDefinedRowId] = [D].[UserDefinedRowId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEMP5] E with (nolock)
ON [A].[UserDefinedRowId] = [E].[UserDefinedRowId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TEMP6] F with (nolock)
ON [A].[UserDefinedRowId] = [F].[UserDefinedRowId]

WHERE ([A].[FieldValue] between @from and @to)
```

Comment: Are the date strings in the proper format?

Comment: What does the SQL look like? What's the full exception stack trace?

Comment: Why is your Date field an `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: yes, 2014-09-04 00:00:00 and 2014-09-11 00:00:00

Comment: how you are comparing dates? I doubt nvarchar understand <= and >=

Comment: Because in column name is fieldvalue and in this column saving not only date

Comment: Are you sure there are rows in all of those temp tables with the UserDefinedRowId?  If even one of those tables don't have an entry for that id, then no row will be returned.  Instead of an inner join, could you try a left join?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Its work then I set values from and to in sql, but with c# not working

Answer (score 1):

I believe using:

```
conn.Open();
```

will solve your problems